# take somebody out to a big restaurant

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have always assumed that the adjective "big" meant "large in size/width/height" when used with physical things and  had related figurative meanings (eg of major importance/relevance, outstanding, large-scale, known) when used with abstract things. For instance, I have always understood "a big restaurant" as a "large restaurant" and a "big problem" as a "complex problem".

Recently, an English native speaker has told me that he understood "big" in the sentence "I'll take you out to a big restaurant" as "famous", "known". May the figurative meanings of "big" may apply to any noun then? If this is true, the real meaning will depend on context, of course.

note: I mean only things on this question. I know that all meanings of "big" may apply when it refers to people.

Comment: Well, possibly...see:  [before noun  informal used to add emphasis:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big)

Comment: I think that this example of the Cambridge dict, available in the link you pasted, already answered my question: "The four biggest banks are all planning to cut their service charges". It is under the definition "important, because of being powerful, or having a lot of influence or a serious effect".

Comment: "Big" can mean many things.  Consider that if a performer is "big on Broadway" that doesn't mean he hulks around on stage, but rather that he draws big crowds and a lot of attention.

Comment: @Hot Licks I already knew that in relation to people, as I mentioned in my original question. My question was about places. Anyway, I have already realized that the figurative meanings of "big" can also be used to things.

Comment: Possibly short-hand for _a [big-name](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big-name) restaurant_.

Comment: 'Big' = 'important' demands that some _measure_ of importance be in place, which involves (usually) human judgment. An otherwise pretty contextless "Tonight, I'm taking you to a big restaurant" sounds unnatural to my ears. With a lot of stress, "Tonight, I'm taking you to a **big** restaurant" or (with less stress needed)  "Tonight, I'm taking you to a _really big_ restaurant"  sounds much better ... a little quirky/jokey ... but the default meaning of 'big' is still 'large', not 'important'. // 'Krystal's little burgers are big in the South' shows an obvious reversal of the default sense.

Comment: Many native speakers have an unsophisticated vocabulary. Would you recommend someone learning your native language to rely on the vocabulary of navies?

Comment: It was a big restaurant **in the late nineties**. No buzzer. Context is everything. Resistance is futile.

Comment: You ask these same types of falsely tricky questions in the Spanish forum. And when you get an answer from someone who sees your game, you ignore it. Vá á luta, irmaõ. Um banco grande nâo é um grande banco **em português**.

Answer (score 0):

Big meaning important:

- They were big importers in the nineties.
- This is a big restaurant among/for Hollywood actors.
- They made big money with that deal.\

BUT, without specific context:

That is a big restaurant. = physically big, unless one is talking in short-hand slang or very colloquially.

As in a conversation that might go like this:

"Yeah, nobody knew it before but now, it's a big restaurant".

big here means a big deal or important as all dictionaries point out.

BUT: "take someone out to a big restaurant" goes to large for most English-speaking ears unless it used as explained above. "take someone out to a restaurant that is big here in New York" = important.

Comment: I've found no examples of "a big restaurant among" and one of "a big restaurant for": "City House was a big restaurant for Nashville." Even this means 'important in that it was ground-breaking'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps not. But your knowledge of English should tell you that "x is big among y [types of people] that big is colloquial for a big deal, for example. Not everything, thank goodness, can be googled. However, one can use one's internalized resources.

Comment: In any case, your 'BUT: "take someone out to a big restaurant" goes to large for most English-speaking ears unless it used as explained above' means that the person OP mentions is violating a Ross constraint (avoid potentially misleading usages, recognising default senses; disambiguate).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I explained it sufficiently well.  big means large unless it means a big deal. It doesn't matter what one calls it. Take someone to a big restaurant. ergo, cannot mean a restaurant that is a big deal. How about saying something positive for once?

Comment: I'm emphasising OP's friend's error, not any you've made.

Answer (score -1):

"big" can also be used with concrete physical things 
with the meaning of "important", "relevant". An example provided by the Cambridge dictionary:

The four biggest banks are all planning to cut their service charges

Reference: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/big

Comment: In the case of banks, I'd interpret "biggest" to mean the one(s) with the most customers or the highest profits, which does make them important but seems to be a use of "big" meaning large rather than important.

Comment: What matters to my question is that "big" in that sentence does not mean "physically large" (they are not necessarily the banks with the biggest offices/agencies), as the Cambridge corresponding definition makes clear. The specific source of the importance (eg popularity, having a lot of clients, having a lot of money)  is irrelevant IMHO.

Comment: This is where it takes skill to read a dictionary: He was a big man on campus. They were big importers in the 90's. But not "big restaurant." Why? Because the context is not clear. Here it is clear: "It was a big restaurant among movies stars".

Comment: You switched from restaurants to banks.....hmm. This would work differently.