# Is “a *big* gift" used here reasonable?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

The original text:

> My mother turned 80 this part fall. One night a few months before, I'd asked her what we could give her and what she would really like.
>
> "Maybe something **big**",I encouraged, knowing that my brothers and I would buy whatever we could afford. I guessed that any gift she might think up would be something like bath salts or a wrinkle cream.

What does the adjective *big* imply about the gift? And is it possible to figure out the time when this conversation happened according to the only context?

Comment: It depends on the way the reader’s mind turns. Financial, physical, emotional - the proposed present can be “big” in any or all of these ways.

Comment: It has been pointed out by researchers that language is often context-dependent: the pragmatics of language is equally as important as semantics and syntax. A big fly is a lot smaller than a small elephant. 'Big' to Mrs Croesus might be half the Lydian Empire; for a penurious widow, it might be a couple of pennies. // Using 'bath salts / face cream' as a yardstick, it would probably be a new TV or laptop rather than a new car. And context rules out 'big as in elephant', the central, non-idiomatic [not 'unidiomatic'] sense of 'big'.

Comment: My guess is *on average*, "a big present" implies ***expensive*** more often than (physically) ***large***. But it's essentially a matter of context and/or opinion.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers.  In this context "something big" generally means something expensive, or something lavish, like a party, not something physically big in size.

Comment: relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505699/take-somebody-out-to-a-big-restaurant

Comment: @Cascabel - Hmm... If someone said they were taking me to a "big restaurant," I would take it to mean they were taking me to a large restaurant, not a majorly important restaurant.  Anyway, that question isn't really relevant to this one since what it's asking about is "big" meaning "of major importance/relevance," not "big" meaning expensive or elaborate.  The meaning of "big" that it's asking about is the meaning of "big" I might use when considering to get married and calling it a "big decision," but "big gift" doesn't convey it's to be of major importance, just extravagant.

Comment: The text states when the conversation happened; a few months before the birthday. I assume '_part_ fall' is a typo for _past_.